# Datagridview on RowLeave not assigning proper values to booleans

Tags: .net, events, datagridview, boolean

I have a DataViewGrid I populated from a DataTable in a query to a DB. While trying to capture the Row_Leave event, so I could properly update it, I can't seem to capture the latest value in boolean columns.

If I update just a text field, when I access the underlying DataSource I get the latest value I entered, buy if I access the boolean, I get the previous value.

I am accessing the Rows like this:

```
if (allCorrect)
{
    if (((DataRowView)dgView.Rows[e.RowIndex].DataBoundItem).IsNew)
    {                        
       this.InsertEntry((DataRow)((DataRowView)dgView.Rows[e.RowIndex].DataBoundItem).Row);
    }
    else
    {                        
        this.UpdateEntry((DataRow)((DataRowView)dgView.Rows[e.RowIndex].DataBoundItem).Row);
    }
 }
```

(quite convoluted way to access the underlying row, but works just like accessing the DataSource of the DGV, so it is not the problem.)

Any ideas?

**EDIT**: I've narrowed the issue to proper event calling. It seems that *RowLeave* gets called before *EndCellEdit* and even *CellValueChanged*. Therefore, the row never gets the status update (to be updated in the DB) and doesn't do it. Can I change the order of these events (as to work properly)? I found out this is a [known issue](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=166608) that was supposed to change in Orcas, but they never did.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, got a workaround it.

After checking that it needs to be updated with:

```
        if(!(dgView.IsCurrentCellDirty))
        {
            return;
        }
```

I do a CommitEdit to apply the changes of the cell (of which event has not happend yet due to the aforementioned bug) with

```
        dgView.CommitEdit(0);
```

and when the the updated/insert happens, the row will get the latest values.